# How do you get all the descendents of a DOM element which have any class defined?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm fairly new to jQuery and javascript in general, and I'm looking to return only the DOM elements which have a class defined. For example:

```
<div id="myObject">
  <h2>hello world</h2>
  <div class="foo">bar</div>
  <div class="bar">foo</div>
  <div></div><a href="http://google.com"></a>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if there exists a jQuery function or a clever search parameter I can pass to `$(#myObject).find(...)` which would return only `.foo` and `.bar`, since those are the only two DOM elements which have a class defined. To generalize, would it also be possible to search for the presence of any attribute?

It seems I can do this using a more complex string of function calls, such as

```
var toReturn = [];
var descendants = $('#myObject').find('*');
$.map(descendants, function (element, index) {
    if(element.getAttribute('class') != undefined){
      toReturn.push(element);
    }
});
```

But if there's something simpler, it would be helpful to know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('#myObject [class]:not([class=""])')`.  It will select all descendants of `#myObject` that have a class defined, and it will exclude elements that have had a class removed.  (Thanks to @TravisJ for the `not` syntax!)

**Snippet:**

```js
$('.byebye').removeClass('byebye');

$('#myObject [class]:not([class=""])').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myObject">
  <h2>hello world</h2>
  <div class="foo">bar</div>
  <div class="bar">foo</div>
  <div class="byebye">
    class removed
  </div>
  <div>
    no class here
  </div>
  <a href="http://google.com">none here either</a>
</div>
```

Comment: To note: if a class has previously had a class, but it was removed with `removeClass()` then it will have an empty `class` attribute that this will still match. For example, you can see this occur if you preface your `addClass` call with `$('.foo').removeClass('foo');`.

Comment: Thanks, @TravisJ, I was not aware of that.  You're absolutely right.

Comment: If it's really necessary to handle that, you can use `.filter()` with a function that checks whether `this.className != ''`

Comment: It would be simple enough to use `not` there, `$('#myObject [class]:not([class=""])')`. This is an edge case, so it may not be necessary though, just extra information really.